# Reset inherited permissions on NTFS folders with Python

Tags: python, permissions, ntfs, pywin32

I have quite a few folders on an NTFS partition (on Windows 2008) which are not inheriting their permissions from their parents.

I'd like to reset that so they do include those parent permissions (equivalent to checking the "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" checkbox under the Advanced Security Settings area).

Since we use Python for some other system management tasks here, I'd like to do it in Python if possible (I know how I can do it in VBScript, but this isn't going to be a one off script, but run regularly, so should integrate with the rest of our codebase).

I've been using the excellent pywin32 extensions and examples from http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i.html and Google to get started, but I don't see any way to simply say "inherit permissions from parent."

Using AddAccessAllowedAceEx, I can even fake inheritance of something by adding the INHERITED_ACE flag in something like, whether it really is coming from the parent or not:

```
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx( \
  win32security.ACL_REVISION_DS \
, win32security.OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE | win32security.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | win32security.INHERITED_ACE \
, ntsecuritycon.FILE_GENERIC_READ | ntsecuritycon.FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE \
, some_sid_here \
)
```

But how in the world do I know which things to inherit unless I walk the entire path from the root folder and build the inheritance all the way down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE and CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE need to be set on the root folder's ACEs.  You'll probably also want to clear any permissions set directly on each subfolder and file. (Those would be the ones that don't include INHERITED_ACE in their ACE flags).

Comment: Both OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE and CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE are set on the root folder's ACEs already. There are no INHERITED_ACE permissions set on the folders at all. When I delete any permissions set directly on the folders, I end up with no permissions at all on the folder. I'm trying to "reset" or "re-add" all the missing INHERITED_ACE flags from the parent that were removed when inheriting was turned off.

Comment: In that case, the security descriptor is probably set to be protected.  This corresponds to unchecking "include inheritable permissions" in the UI.  You should be able to either remove the

Comment: security descriptor altogether by setting it to None, or set it using UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION.

Comment: Setting the security descriptor to None seems to have the same effect as removing all ACEs... removes all permissions and does not reset anything.  You may be on to something with the UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION although I can't seem to query it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573(v=vs.85).aspx says I shouldn't be able to anyway) and I can't seem to figure out how to set it/write to it.

Comment: You can check for it by checking if the flags returned by GetSecurityDescriptorControl include SE_DACL_PROTECTED.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely seems to help me check for it, but I already know the folders aren't inheriting. Removing that flag doesn't do anything either. I'll try and play with it some more tomorrow.

Comment: Are you starting from the top of the hierarchy ?  If you have root folder->subfolder->subsubfolder, you'll need to make sure subfolder is inheriting before subsubfolder will ever show any inherited permissions.

Comment: root folder->subfolder1->subfolder2 ARE inheriting, but then: root folder->subfolder1->subfolder2->subfolder3 isn't and neither is root folder->subfolder1->subfolder2->subfolder3->subfolder4. If I can reset subfolder3, then I can build something to walk the full path and reset all, but I have to figure out how to reset subfolder3 first.

Comment: What are the current permissions for the problem folder set to ?

Comment: Turns out you were right, I just wasn't going about it the right way. I needed to set UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, I just didn't know where to do it. Here is the line of code that I got to do it: win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo(path, win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | win32security.UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, None, None, dacl, None)